# What is the curl command to upload a list of files from an input form in flask?

Tags: python, curl, flask

I need the curl command to upload a list of files from a form file input field. What I have tried:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8081/rt/api/v1.0/add -d '{"title":"Website updated", "description": "Not accessible", "requestor":"abc@ytz.com", "mfiles":["file1.txt","file2.txt"]}' -H 'Content-type:Application/json'
```

The api to upload the files:

```
  for f in request.files.getlist('mfiles'):
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(upload_folder, filename))
```

This gives me error: `Statement is not an insert() expression construct.`

What is the exact curl to do so? I am using Flask 0.12, python 2.7

Comment: With your curl command you are just posting json data to `/rt/api/v1.0/add` path. In order to upload file(s) via curl you will have to run something like this: `curl -F ‘data1=@path/to/file’  -F ‘data2=@path/to/file’ URL`. Also, it doesn't look like the error above is related to your flask code snippet. Can you clarify what is the exact thing you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boris, Yes. I should have used an input form. And the curl used to upload multiple files is:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8081/rt/api/v1.0/add -F "title=some title MM" -F "description=Not accessible" -F "mfiles=@crons.txt" -F "mfiles=@temp.txt" -F "mfiles=@duplicates.txt"
```